# How to share the Zoom window itself in Zoom?

Tags: screen-sharing, recursive, zoom-meeting

I want to interactively demonstrate how to use the Zoom meeting room controls to a Zoom meeting.
However, Zoom doesn't seem to offer a way to share the actual Zoom window (the one you see when there is no screen sharing). Is there a command that I'm missing?

Comment: I would imagine you would need a third-party application, that is able to share your desktop, and switch the camera within zoom to that output.  To my knowledge Zoom doesn't have the capable to do what you want.

Comment: Zoom has Tutorials.  I think it would be OK to take a screen shot of a relevant control to use in a training session

Answer (score 1):

One option is to use a second webinar application, like Webex or Teams, then demonstrate Zoom controls on the shared screen. (That's not what you're asking, but it's an interesting workaround. I do this sort of thing often, as the capability to share an screen sharing application's own windows isn't always available.)

If you have at least version 3.6 of the client, then you can share Zoom windows. However the steps vary by version. In older (but >= 3.6) clients:

1. On the Zoom web site, open your Settings > In Meeting (Basic) and enable **Show Zoom windows during screen share**
2. In the client's Settings > Share Screen, there is an option to **Show Zoom windows during screen share**.

Sometime into version 5 of the client, the switch for step 2 was removed:
[image: Zoom client 5.5.2 doesn't have Show Zoom windows during screen share option]

Just enable it on the website.
[image: Show Zoom windows during screen share option enabled on website]